# TI-Basic on the ti-84

Tags: ti-basic

I want to use the "Calculate-Intersect" in a program, but when going to the sub-menu in a program editor it just puts me in the users screen and not a command. Are there any commands / ways of getting and solving x or y's with a y1?

Answer (score 2):

You can effectively find the intersect of two Y variables in TI-83 Basic by using the solve() function.

Assuming Y<sub>1</sub> and Y<sub>2</sub>, and N is a guess of what the x value of the intersect is (you could just use 0), are the two functions that you want to find the intersect of, then:

```
solve(Y1 - Y2, X, N) → A
```

will store the x coordinate of the intersect to A, and then:

```
A → X
Y1 → B
```

will store the Y value of the intersect to B.

This is probably the fastest way to find the intersect of two functions in TI-83 basic because it relies on inbuilt functions instead of slow loops to find the intersect.

Edit:

As pointed out by Sentherus Argentum in the comments, the y value of the coordinate can be stored to B with just `Y1(A) → B`

Comment: If you want to avoid storing to X and would prefer the answer immediately, just use Y1(A) to get the value for B.

Comment: @Sentherus Argentum I haven't used a ti-84 since I upgraded to the ti-88, so I wasn't sure if that was valid in TI83-Basic

Comment: It still is, just wanted to make sure that it's known to those who might want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Ti-Basic has only got commands to find stuff about single funtions like the `fMin(`, `fMax(` and `solve(` commands. I'm afraid the ti-basic language has no access to the CALC-Menu options.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
:For(X,Xmin,Xmax,ΔX)
:If Y1(X)=Y2(X):Then
:Y1(X)→Y :Disp X,Y :Xmax→X
:Else
:(Y1(X)-Y2(X))/abs(Y1(X)-Y2(X))→Z
:(Y1(X-ΔX)-Y2(X-ΔX))/abs(Y1(X-ΔX)-Y2(X-ΔX))→W
:If W≠Z:Then
:Y1(X)→Y :Disp X,Y :Xmax→X:End
:End
:End
```